# Verify that $v^s(-p)^{\dagger}\gamma^0u^s(p) = 0$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-equation, spinors

Given that
$$
\gamma^0 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0\\
0 & -I\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Where $I$ is 2 by 2 identity matrix.

and the Dirac spinors
$$
u^s(p) = \sqrt{E_p+m}\begin{bmatrix}
\xi^s \\
\frac{p\cdot\sigma}{E_p+m}\xi^s  \\
\end{bmatrix}\qquad v^s(-p) = \sqrt{E_p+m}\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{p\cdot\sigma}{E_p+m}\xi^s  \\
\xi^s  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I'm trying to show that $v^s(-p)^{\dagger}\gamma^0u^s(p) = 0$. By doing the matrix multiplication, I got
$$
v^s(-p)^{\dagger}\gamma^0u^s(p) = (E_p+m)(-\xi^{s\dagger}\xi^{s'}\frac{p\cdot\sigma}{E_p+m}-\xi^{s\dagger}\xi^{s'}\frac{p\cdot\sigma}{E_p+m})
$$

Now I got confused, I don't think the expression above is $0$, but I can't find any mistakes with my calculation. How can I show that $v^s(-p)^{\dagger}\gamma^0u^s(p) = 0$, using the definition above? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possibly relevant:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/370914/orthogonality-relations-for-spinors-of-plane-wave-solution

Comment: As you can see at the link, the usual orthogonality relation that holds between $u$ and $v$ states is $\bar{v}(p)u(p)=v(p)^{\dagger}\gamma^{0}u(p)=0$.  So it looks like you may be working from a source that uses a different convention for the meaning of $v(-p)$ from the usual one.  (The difference would amount to whether the energy-momentum $p$ belongs to a Dirac sea electron state or to the positron state that is absence of that electron state.)